# tab order with 3 GroupBoxes don't go well

Tags: c#, winforms

when i order tab i use View>Tab Order

I have 3 GroupBoxes in window forms : GroupBox A , GroupBox B, GroupBox C

GroupBox C is within the GroupBox B

GroupBox B is within the GroupBox A

GroupBox A Tab Order is 0
Controls in that group box are like 0.1, 0.2, 0....

GroupBox B Tab Order is 0.0
Controls in that group box are like 0.0.1, 0.0.2, 0.0.3,....

GroupBox C Tab Order is 0.0.0
Controls in that group box are like 0.0.0.1, 0.0.0.2, 0.0.0.3,....

when i run the form i got focus in a TextBox of GroupBox C.

what i want is GroupBox A, GroupBox B and GroupBox C

what do i suppose to do ?

Answer (score 4):

using View>Tab Order:

You need to make sure you **click on the tab number for the groupbox** first then the controls within the groupbox.

[image]

Your tabs should then become:

GroupBox A Tab Order is 0 Controls like     0.1, 0.2, 0....
GroupBox B Tab Order is 0.1 Controls like   0.1.1, 0.1.2, 0.1.3,....
GroupBox C Tab Order is 0.1.1 Controls like 0.1.1.1, 0.1.1.2, 0.1.1.3,....

Answer (score 2):

Try selecting the GroupBoxA within the form load. This will make sure that GroupBox A gets focus when form loads.

```
GroupBoxA.Select();
```

Comment: @AccessDenied i doesn't work tab order started in group box C then B then C help

Comment: @donata how you want the tab to work ? first set focus on a textbox in box A and go to each and every control in box A then move to box B controls and finally go to box C ?